# Calculate how often specific daytime is contained in time range

Tags: java, date, time, calendar, timezone

I have a time range starting with a start date and end date represented in milliseconds since 1970:

```
long start;
long end;
```

And I want to know if and how often a specific daytime is contained in this range. So let's say the daytime is 09.00 am DST - how often is it contained in the range.

Is there an easy and elegant way to calculate this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes.

Convert your count-from-epoch numbers. An `Instant` is a point on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant startInstant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( startLong ) ;
Instant stopInstant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( stopLong ) ;
```

Adjust into your desired time zone.

Always use true time zone names structured as `continent/region`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = instantStart.atZone( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = instantStop.atZone( z ) ;
```

Represent your target time-of-day.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 9 , 0 ) ;
```

Get a `ZonedDateTime` with your starting date and your target time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStartAtTargetTime = ZonedDateTime.of( zdtStart.toLocalDate() , lt , z ) ;
```

Compare that to your interval’s start to see if you should count this starting date.

Do the same process for the last day.

The count the days between the start of the second day and first moment of the last day.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop ) ;
```

If they count, add your first day, and your last day.

Compare to the

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, you could use `java.time.OffsetDateTime`, starting from your start point, adjusting the time based on `toOffsetTime`, then repeatedly using `plusDays` until you've exceeded your end time.

If not, then you can achieve something similar with Joda's `DateTime` class.

Don't try it without a library that handles calendars properly.

Comment: FYI, the *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance mode. The team recommends migration to the *java.time* classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTenABP* project.